# Do I have to transform my data? Issue of Normal distribution in a unique data set

Tags: distributions, anova, normal-distribution, data-transformation, normality-assumption

[![Descriptive Statistics
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Uok.jpg)[[image: Between Subjects main effect]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SFTW.jpg)[[image: ][1]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KAlN.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Uok.jpg)[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAcV0.jpg)[[image: Descriptive Stats[![Withi Subject main effect[![Normality on Raw Data[![Main Effects]][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsTOs.jpg)][6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Luy4A.jpg)][7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmOwa.jpg)][8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZflI9.jpg)

I have recorded the electrical response at a specific brain region by applying pulses to the region of interest. The electrical stimulation was applied in pairs (at varying interpulse intervals), resulting in a paired response. I measured the slope of the first $P_1$ and second pulse $P_2$ and calculated the "Paired-Pulse Index" by the following formula:

$$\text{Paired-Pulse Index (PPI)} = \frac{P_2-P_1}{P_1} \cdot 100.$$

Some values are positive and some negative.  When checking for normality, data from some of my treatment groups are not normally distributed. I can not use Log, SQRT, arcsin transformations. Using the Sin transformation only resolves the issue for some data sets but not all and it completely changes the results of my 2-way ANOVA.

what is the best way to deal with this issue?
Is the GLM not robust enough to deal with a few non-normally distributed data sets? Also, given that all values have been normalised to their own $P_1$, is normalising the data further  necessary ?

Comment: Please tell us why you check for normality: what procedure are you planning to use that requires your data to have a normal distribution?  (Very few procedures have such a requirement.)

Comment: More generally, can you please explain your research question: what is it you want to know about the paired-data values you are taking?

Comment: I have 2 treatment groups ( n=11/group) and they have undergone 7 types of stimulation. I want to use a Mixed design ANOVA  ( Treatment and stimulation type) to determine main effect of treatment, main effect of stimulation type and their interaction. As part of the assumptions for ANOVA, i checked my data for normality, And a few data sets were not normally distributed. My question is : 1. Do I have to transform the data given that each value has been normalised to its own p1 ? 2. What kind of transformation can O use for Negative data ?

Comment: It might help people come up with useful answers if you would run a preliminary ANOVA, save the residuals, and post a graph of them for each group.